# Issue importing CSV file to QGIS and use it as shapefile

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file to work on a point shapefile in QGIS 3.14

In Excel, my CSV is as follow : ID, X&Y coordinates, and another field (H)

[image]

I then go to Layer - Add a Layer - Add a text-delimited layer and import the CSV with the following parameters :

[image]

But upon importing, my CSV does not show as a shapefile, it shows with the csv icon (the TEST layer) and I cannot do anything with it (I cannot display the points, or the label)...
If think my QGIS configuration might have changed....
How can I correctly import the CSV file ?

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the dialog. It shows in the preview perfectly and the coordinates are valid and X and Y are there. Can you share the file?

Answer (score 3):

You have checked the box DMS coordinates (Coordonnées DMS) but your coordinates seem to be in decimal degrees. This could be the problem.